# Stack column chart in PowerBI with date on x-asix and count on y-axis

Tags: powerbi, column-chart

I have a data in below format and looking to get a stacked column chart as below. I am not sure how to club the dates and count together which are in multiple columns.

My data

[image]

I want to represent the above data in a clustered column chart where data on X-axis is clubbed in month and on Y-axis is clubbed with count of Yes per month like below based on different project types.

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You will need to transform your data, add a Date table, add a relationship, and possibly a measure to do this.

**1. Transform your data**
You should unpivot your columns in PowerQuery to give you a table structure similar to this:

| Project | Test | Date | Result |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| A | Test A | 01/05/2023 | Yes |

Here is an example query to do this:

```
let
    Source = Table.FromRows(Json.Document(Binary.Decompress(Binary.FromText("i45WclTSUTIw1Dcw1TcyMDIGciJTi4GkiT5QAMEFoVidaCUnKBuGDI31DcwQCkFKnEHC+hbIug2N9A0NUAQwdLkA2UbG+oaG6LYChVFEY2MB", BinaryEncoding.Base64), Compression.Deflate)), let _t = ((type nullable text) meta [Serialized.Text = true]) in type table [Project = _t, #"Test A Date Approved" = _t, #"Test A Result" = _t, #"Test B Date Approved" = _t, #"Test B Result" = _t, #"Test C Date Approved" = _t, #"Test C Result" = _t]),
    #"Changed Type" = Table.TransformColumnTypes(Source,{{"Project", type text}, {"Test A Date Approved", type date}, {"Test A Result", type text}, {"Test B Date Approved", type date}, {"Test B Result", type text}, {"Test C Date Approved", type date}, {"Test C Result", type text}}),
    #"Unpivoted Columns" = Table.UnpivotOtherColumns(#"Changed Type", {"Project"}, "Attribute", "Value"),
    #"Date Filtered Rows" = Table.SelectRows(#"Unpivoted Columns", each Text.Contains([Attribute], "Approved")),
    #"Date Renamed Columns" = Table.RenameColumns(#"Date Filtered Rows",{{"Value", "Date"}, {"Attribute", "Test"}}),
    #"Date Replaced Value" = Table.ReplaceValue(#"Date Renamed Columns"," Date Approved","",Replacer.ReplaceText,{"Test"}),
    #"Result Filtered Rows" = Table.SelectRows(#"Unpivoted Columns", each Text.Contains([Attribute], "Result")),
    #"Result Renamed Columns" = Table.RenameColumns(#"Result Filtered Rows",{{"Attribute", "Test"}, {"Value", "Result"}}),
    #"Result Replaced Value" = Table.ReplaceValue(#"Result Renamed Columns"," Result","",Replacer.ReplaceText,{"Test"}),
    Merge = Table.NestedJoin(#"Date Replaced Value", {"Project", "Test"}, #"Result Replaced Value", {"Project", "Test"}, "ResultMerge", JoinKind.LeftOuter),
    #"Expanded ResultMerge" = Table.ExpandTableColumn(Merge, "ResultMerge", {"Result"}, {"Result"}),
    #"Changed Type1" = Table.TransformColumnTypes(#"Expanded ResultMerge",{{"Date", type date}, {"Result", type text}})
in
    #"Changed Type1"
```

**2. Create a Date table**
There are multiple ways to do this. For example, you can create a Calculated Table with the following DAX:

```
Dim Date = ADDCOLUMNS(
    CALENDARAUTO(),
    "Month", FORMAT([Date], "mmmm"),
    "Month#", MONTH([Date])
  )
```

Then right-click on this new `Dim Date` table and `Mark as date table`, select `Date` as the Date column. Next, select `Month` column and in the ribbon select `Sort by column` and select the `Month#` column.

**3. Create a relationship**
Now create a relationship between your `Dim Date` table to your test results table on the Date columns in each. It should look like:
[image]

**4. Create your chart**
Now you will be able to create your chart as show below. Select `Show items with no data` to see consecutive months.
[image]

Comment: Many thanks Sam, this is exactly what I wanted. Thanks again for your detailed explanation and clear steps.

Comment: Alternate powerquery would be  #"Unpivoted Columns" = Table.UnpivotOtherColumns(Source, {"Project"}, "Attribute", "Value"),
    #"Replaced Value" = Table.ReplaceValue(#"Unpivoted Columns","Date Approved","Date",Replacer.ReplaceText,{"Attribute"}),
    #"Split Column by Delimiter" = Table.SplitColumn(#"Replaced Value", "Attribute", Splitter.SplitTextByEachDelimiter({" "}, QuoteStyle.Csv, true), {"Test", "Attribute.2"})
    in  Table.Pivot(#"Split Column by Delimiter", List.Distinct(#"Split Column by Delimiter"[Attribute.2]), "Attribute.2", "Value")

Comment: Very nice @horseyride